# Avoiding \hline and \multicolumn in table

Tags: tables, multicol

I have a table as the following. The journal that I am submitting to doesn't allow \hline or \multicolumn. Do you know how I can have a similar table (similar look) but avoiding \hline and \multicolumn? I tried to convert it to a pdf or eps and import it as figure. But the journal doesn't allow pdf either and eps will ruin all the fonts (convert . to strange symbol).

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Regression Results} 
  \label{} 
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}% Tighter
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Grade} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Satisfaction} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Degree & -10.887^{***}  & -1.195^{***} \\ 
  & (-3.793)& (-4.937) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 BS Major & -12.821^{**} & -0.676 \\ 
  & (-2.580 )& (-1.612) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 Gender & 0.106 & 0.147 \\ 
  & (0.028 )& (0.457) \\ 
  & & \\ 

\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{86} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{86} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.313} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.467} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.200} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.379} \\ 
Residual Std. Error (df = 73) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.126} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.686} \\ 
F Statistic (df = 12; 73) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.766$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.327$^{***}$} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{@{} l}{The dependent variable are grade and satisfaction.} \\ 
 \textit{}  & \multicolumn{2}{@{} l}{t-statistics are shown in parentheses.} \\ 
\textit{Significance levels:}  & \multicolumn{2}{@{} l}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 

\end{tabular} 
\label{table:regression}
\end{table}
```

Comment: if they say they don't want \hline or \multicolumn then it is not the _commands_ they do not want it is that they do not want horizontal rules or spanning cells so the whole point is _not_ to have that look. Trying to make horizontal rules and spans using different tex commands or by including the table as an image just defeat the purpose and more than likely make the paper not be accepted.

Comment: that said `\multicolumn{1}{c}` isn't a spanning cell at all so that is easily avoided.

Comment: what's the intention of `\hline\\[-1.8ex]` ?  the `\\ ` after `\hline` creates a spurious row then the negative space more or less hides it??

Comment: Strange they do not want horizontal lines at all. Usually, one avoids vertical lines and too many horizontal lines…

Comment: Yes, I can get rid of \multicolumn{1}{c}. But If I will have a regular table, it will be a really dull and boring one (the table is actually longer than the code I have here). So I thought the reason they do not want /hline, etc. is because they don't want it to be simple to edit (since the journal edits the tex).